# Can't add SQL Query in SQL server report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a report using  SQL server report on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. The issue I'm facing is when i try to add query in new Dataset i get en error saying 'Could not update a list of fields for the query.  Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct.' . I'm not getting the issue when creating other reports and the query works just fine on SQL server but it seems like i have to re-write the query in different way so that it will work on SQL server report. I'm not sure how i should re-write the query and what's the issue exactly .

the query is:

```
-- PreTerm Still birth

WITH
cteCond1Pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(d.DiseaseID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.AdmissionID ORDER BY pd.DiseaseID) AS secondDia
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          LEFT JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.PatientID = pa.PatientID
     WHERE pd.DiseaseID IN (139061, 128466, 128462, 128463, 128464, 128465, 128466, 128467, 128663, 128662, 128661, 104860, 104859, 104857, 1397)
       AND pa.PatientType = 2),
cteCond1 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS PreTerm_Still_Birth,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond1Pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond1Pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS
     FROM cteCond1Pre
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON d.DiseaseID = cteCond1Pre.secondDia
     WHERE cteCond1Pre.DiseaseID IN (128466, 128462, 128463, 128464, 128465, 128466, 128467, 128663, 128662, 128661, 104860, 104859, 104857, 1397)
       AND cteCond1Pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
       AND cteCond1Pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10')
       AND secondDia IN (139061)


-- FullTerm Still birth
),
cteCond2Pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(d.DiseaseID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.AdmissionID ORDER BY pd.DiseaseID) AS secondDia
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          LEFT JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.Patientid = pa.PatientID
     WHERE pd.DiseaseID NOT IN (128466, 128462, 128463, 128464, 128465, 128466, 128467, 128663, 128662, 128661, 104860, 104859, 104857, 1397)
       AND pa.PatientType = 2),
cteCond2 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS FullTerm_Still_Birth,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond2Pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S2,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond2Pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS2
     FROM cteCond2Pre
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON d.DiseaseID = cteCond2Pre.secondDia
     WHERE cteCond2Pre.DiseaseID NOT IN (128462, 128463, 128464, 128465, 128466, 128467, 128663, 128662, 128661, 104860, 104859, 104857, 1397)
       AND secondDia IN (139061)
       AND cteCond2Pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
       AND cteCond2Pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10')),



--Fullterm_Live_Birth 
cteCond3Pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(pa.AdmitDate) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.regcode ORDER BY pa.admitdate) AS next_AdmitDate,
            pa.PatientID,
            p.FirstName
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.ParentPatientid = pa.PatientID
          JOIN v_dbpatients p ON p.PatientID = pe.PatientID
     WHERE pd.DiseaseID IN (139060)),
cteCond3 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Fullterm_Live_Birth,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond3Pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S3,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond3Pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS3
     FROM cteCond3Pre
     WHERE cteCond3Pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
       AND cteCond3Pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10')),

-- fullterm Low Birth weight
cteCond4Pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(d.DiseaseID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.AdmissionID ORDER BY pd.DiseaseID) AS secondDia
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          JOIN v_dbpatients pp ON pp.PatientID = pa.PatientID
          LEFT JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.Patientid = pa.PatientID
     WHERE pd.DiseaseID IN (104846, 104847, 104848, 104849, 104850, 104851, 104852, 104853, 8103, 8102, 104843)
       AND pa.PatientType = 2),
cteCond4 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Fullterm_Low_BirthWeight,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond4Pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond4Pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS
     FROM cteCond4Pre
     WHERE cteCond4Pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
       AND cteCond4Pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10')),


-- Delivery_Other-Twinss
cteCond5Pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(d.DiseaseID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.AdmissionID ORDER BY pd.DiseaseID) AS secondDia
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          JOIN v_dbpatients pp ON pp.PatientID = pa.PatientID
          LEFT JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.Patientid = pa.PatientID
     WHERE pa.PatientType = 2),
cteCond5 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Delivery_Other_Twinss,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond5Pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond5Pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS
     FROM cteCond5Pre
     WHERE cteCond5Pre.DiseaseID IN (11866)
        OR (cteCond5Pre.DiseaseID IN (128576)
        AND cteCond5Pre.secondDia IN (139060)
        AND cteCond5Pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
        AND cteCond5Pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10'))),


-- Delivery_CS
cteCond6Pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(d.DiseaseID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.AdmissionID ORDER BY pd.DiseaseID) AS secondDia
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          JOIN v_dbpatients pp ON pp.PatientID = pa.PatientID
          LEFT JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.Patientid = pa.PatientID
     WHERE pd.DiseaseID IN (140540)
       AND pa.PatientType = 2),
cteCond6 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Delivery_CS,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond6Pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond6Pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS
     FROM cteCond6Pre
     WHERE cteCond6Pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
       AND cteCond6Pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10')),


-- Delivery_Forceps
cteCond7Pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(d.DiseaseID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.AdmissionID ORDER BY pd.DiseaseID) AS secondDia
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          JOIN v_dbpatients pp ON pp.PatientID = pa.PatientID
          LEFT JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.Patientid = pa.PatientID
     WHERE pd.DiseaseID IN (140539)
       AND pa.PatientType = 2),
cteCond7 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Delivery_Forceps,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond7Pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond7Pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS
     FROM cteCond7Pre
     WHERE cteCond7Pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
       AND cteCond7Pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10')),



-- Delivery_Breech
cteCond8Pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(d.DiseaseID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.AdmissionID ORDER BY pd.DiseaseID) AS secondDia
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          JOIN v_dbpatients pp ON pp.PatientID = pa.PatientID
          LEFT JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.Patientid = pa.PatientID
     WHERE pd.DiseaseID IN (128680, 104824)
       AND pa.PatientType = 2),
cteCond8 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Delivery_Breech,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond8Pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond8Pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS
     FROM cteCond8Pre
     WHERE cteCond8Pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
       AND cteCond8Pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10')),



-- Delivery_Ventouse(Vacuum Extractor)
cteCond9Pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(d.DiseaseID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.AdmissionID ORDER BY pd.DiseaseID) AS secondDia
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          JOIN v_dbpatients pp ON pp.PatientID = pa.PatientID
          LEFT JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.Patientid = pa.PatientID
     WHERE pd.DiseaseID IN (140539)
       AND pa.PatientType = 2),
cteCond9 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Delivery_Ventouse,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond9Pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond9Pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS
     FROM cteCond9Pre
     WHERE (cteCond9Pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
        AND cteCond9Pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10'))),

-- Delivery_Normal-Single-Spontanous
cteCond10pre AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            pa.AdmitDate,
            pa.AdmissionID,
            pa.RegCode,
            d.DiseaseName,
            d.DiseaseID,
            pe.NationalityID,
            LEAD(d.DiseaseID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.AdmissionID ORDER BY pd.DiseaseID) AS secondDia
     FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
          JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
          JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
          JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON pd.DiseaseID = d.DiseaseID
          JOIN v_dbpatients pp ON pp.PatientID = pa.PatientID
          LEFT JOIN v_dbPatientsAdditions pe ON pe.Patientid = pa.PatientID
     WHERE pd.DiseaseID IN (140538)
       AND pa.PatientType = 2),
cteCond10 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Delivery_Normal_Single_Spontanous,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond10pre.NationalityID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS S,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cteCond10pre.NationalityID != 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) AS NS
     FROM cteCond10pre
     WHERE cteCond10pre.AdmitDate > '2019-01-01'
       AND cteCond10pre.AdmitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-10-10'))
SELECT *
FROM cteCond1
     CROSS JOIN cteCond2
     CROSS JOIN cteCond3
     CROSS JOIN cteCond4
     CROSS JOIN cteCond5
     CROSS JOIN cteCond6
     CROSS JOIN cteCond7
     CROSS JOIN cteCond8
     CROSS JOIN cteCond9
     CROSS JOIN cteCond10;
```

Comment: Such errors normally mean that the query generates an error; I would suggest trying to run the query first and see what result you get.

Comment: I already executed the query on SQL server and the query has no Errors

Comment: Without a way to replicate this, this is impossible for us to suggest much else. perhaps use a Trace/Extended event to capture the SQL that SSRS is running, and then run that to see what the error is.

Comment: Your query will create a resultset containing multiple columns with the same name. Laziness is not your friend here - each column will require a unique name. So just get on with the tedious work you created for yourself.

Comment: for the output I've already gave them aliases as S,NS  for the first subquery and S1,NS1 for the second subquery etc...  . Do you mean the column's in the select ? Please be patient I'm not really good with SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a semi-colon (;) before the WITH

Answer (score 0):

I've created multiple datasets  on SSRS for each subquery and it worked fine !